# I am sending an int object on a socket connection but on recieving it, the result is b' '. What can I do to keep it an int object?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

This is the client side which is sending the code:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
code=123
try:
    sock.connect(('192.168.1.10',12345))
    sock.send(code)
    print(sock.recv(1024).decode('ascii'))
finally:
    sock.close()
```

Comment: My advice is that you don't send raw binary objects over the network. Instead [*serialize*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the data into a format than can then be easily de-serialized at the other end.

Comment: I tried but larger int throw an error when converted into bytes object.

Comment: You could make it a string first, then encode that to bytes: `sock.send(str(code).encode("ASCII"))`. Also then you don't have to worry about the byte length (compared to using `int.to_bytes`).